# Como imprimir una imagen con DomPDF en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

Estoy realizando un pdf, para lo cual utilizo la libreria: **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf**, en el pdf trato de imprimir una imagen, con lo cual al momento de abrir el archivo recientemente descargado, se imprimen todos los datos menos la imagen, **aclaro esta imagen si se visualiza correctamente en mi vista show.blade**, no encuentro solución para este inconveniente.
A continuación detallo de que manera estoy procediendo:

Controlador: (fragmento de metodo store y metodo exportPdf)

```
    public function store(SaveDocumentRequest $request)
    {
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {               

        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);   
    }else{
          $name = null; 
    }  
   $document->photo  = $name;
```

```
    public function exportPdf()
    {
        $movie = Movies::with('document.creator', 'actors', 'generate_movie', 'document.adequacy', 'document.lenguage')->first();

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.movies.show', compact('movie'));  
       
        return $pdf->download('cine.pdf');
    }
```

Mi archivo show.blade

```
<div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Imagen de Portada </h3>
            </div>        
            <div class="box-body box-profile">                                          
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('/images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}"  alt="{{ $movie->document->title }}" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**De esta manera estoy accediendo a la imagen que si se muestra correctamente en mi archivo show.blade, pero no se visualiza en el pdf descargado.**

**Aclaro no recibo ningún tipo de error y la imagen se almacena en la carpeta public del proyecto.**

Podrían guiarme para encontrar la solución?

Comment: Si estas trabajando en localhost, no lo verás, la ruta debe estar disponible desde cualquier lugar. Cuando el sitio esté en producción, el método que tienes va a funcionar

Comment: Intenta sin asset(), simplemente `'images/...`

Comment: @Jonathan Orta, si efectivamente estoy trabajando en localhost, entonces no hay forma de imprimí y visualizar la imagen, Salvo que esté en producción? También existe una opción configurable en dompdf enable_remote => false , esa opción no la comprendo

Comment: Pasale el path de la imagen en vez de la url. Algo así `<img src="{{ public_path('/images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}" >`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  he realizado el cambio sugerido ```src="{{ public_path('/images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}"``` pero recibo el siguiente error: ```Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/biblioteca/public//images/1597187286alien.jpg```, puedes ver que en la ruta me esta agregando  2 barras (//) ```/public//images/1597187286alien.jpg```, con lo cual a tu respuesta le he sacado la primer barra diagonal ```<img src="{{ public_path('images/'....```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ tambien he probado con esto ```{{ base_path('images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}```,  no me ha funcionado. Por otro lado he leido que para pdf se necesita convertir la imagen a base_64, entonces cuando estoy guardando una imagen recien ahi la tendria que guardar en base_64? si es asi podrias revisar mi metodo store lo he subido ahi muestro como guardo la imagen

Comment: Ok, está bien que le sacaste esa barra. Puedes usar imágenes en formatos binarios, pero debes tener instalada la extensión GD de PHP y algunas otras. Puedes ver la extensiones requeridas y las recomendadas en la documentación de dompdf https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#recommendations

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, revise la documentacion y dice esto: Soporte de imágenes (gif, png (8, 24 y 32 bits con canal alfa), bmp y jpeg) la imagen que subo es .jpg entonces por lo que veo no tiene soporte

Comment: jpg es lo mismo que jpeg. Probaste con un PNG? De todas maneras tienes que tener instalada y habilitada la extensión GD.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ fui a C:\xampp\php\php.ini y observo que ya tengo esta extension habilitada: ```extension=gd2``` mi version de php es: 7.2.4

Comment: Prueba pasarle harcodeado el path donde tienes la imagen. `src="{{ public_path('images/1597187286alien.jpg' ) }}"`. Hace poco hice algo con esa librería y esa parte la hago así. Puede ser un tema de extensiones, de permisos (tiene que existir ciertos directorios de cache con permiso de escritura). O que esté mal el path. Te muestra la imagen si cargás el html en el navegador?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ de la manera que me indicas tal cual esta recibo este error: ```Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/biblioteca/public/images/1597588609alien.jpg```, ahora respondiendo tu pregunta, con esto ```<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}" >``` si puedo ver la imagen en el navegador y cuando descargo el pdf la imagen no aparece =(

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ sugiero ir al chat

Answer (score -1):

yo la imprimo de esta manera,

```
  <img src="{{ asset('images/logo_small.png') }}" width="90" />
```

depende donde la tengas almacenada, en public o en storage..

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]